# Get STATUS from table by which join in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have a query for which based on `CRNO` I get the STATUS from another table. So the below query is

`select a.crno, a.crno_date, a.state, a.status_rank from R4G_OSP.ENODEB  a
Where a.crno is not null
and a.crno = 'R4G-MH-NLD-7718'
and a.status_rank is not null
order by 4 asc;`

and STATUS table query is

`select * from APP_WFM.WFM_CANDIDATE_STATUS where rank = 20`

So, now I want to join the query and get the status in the first query. How should I do that

The sample data of both query is below

**QUERY 1 SAMPLE DATA**

[image: IMG 1]

**QUERY 2 SAMPLE DATA**

[image: IMG 2]

Please suggest how should I get the STATUS by joining it

Comment: Read a bit about  SQL joins...

Comment: @KaushikNayak: sure I will, but can you guide me how should I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JOIN`. Manual [Here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/)

```
select a.crno, 
       a.crno_date, 
       a.state, 
       a.status_rank,
       APP_WFM.WFM_CANDIDATE_STATUS.STATUS
from R4G_OSP.ENODEB  a
join APP_WFM.WFM_CANDIDATE_STATUS on APP_WFM.WFM_CANDIDATE_STATUS.RANK = a.status_rank
Where a.crno is not null
and a.crno = 'R4G-MH-NLD-7718'
and a.status_rank is not null
order by 4 asc;
```

If you want only rank 20 add `AND a.status_rank = 20` before `ORDER BY`

Comment: thanks alberto for quick response, also how to get the status column from second query ?

Comment: added like this `AND APP_WFM.WFM_CANDIDATE_STATUS.STATUS = a.status_rank` but getting error as ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: for status add APP_WFM.WFM_CANDIDATE_STATUS.STATUS in select. I modify my query

Comment: I have second query related to this, which I will ask in next question in some time. Hope you can answer it that too..

Comment: maybe it's similar to this, read the manual and try a few tests. If you fail, I will be happy to help you

Comment: hi albert, `SELECT STATUS_RANK, DECODE(STATUS_RANK > 23, 'POST HOTO', STATUS_RANK < 23, 'PRE HOTO') STATUSRANK
FROM  APP_WFM.WFM_CANDIDATE_STATUS.RANK;` this decode is not working for me.. can u see

Comment: Decode dosen't exist in MySql, use [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)`(CASE  WHEN STATUS_RANK > 23 THEN 'POST HOTO'  WHEN STATUS_RANK < 23 THEN 'PRE HOTO' END)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select a.crno, 
     a.crno_date, 
     a.state, 
     a.status_rank 
   from R4G_OSP.ENODEB  a
   join APP_WFM.WFM_CANDIDATE_STATUS on APP_WFM.WFM_CANDIDATE_STATUS.RANK = a.status_rank
   and a.crno = 'R4G-MH-NLD-7718'
   and a.status_rank is not null
   order by 4 asc;
```

Based on the sample data of the table provided  it is seen that the primary key relationship is set on WFM.WFM_CANDIDATE_STATUS.RANK and status_rank of another table so you can easily join between those columns